# How can I transform this system into a first order system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to transform a system into a first order system.

The system is the following:

$u''(t)=\frac{v(t)}{1+t^2}-sin(r(t))$

$v''(t)=\frac{-u(t)}{1+t^2}+cos(r(t))$

where $r(t)=\sqrt{(u'(t))^2+(v'(t))^2}$.

I have done the next: $r(t)r'(t)=u'(t)u''(t)+v'(t)v''(t)$ and I tried to use the system, but I dont know how to put all this together...

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z = (u,u',v,v') = (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ then we have,

$$ z_2' = \frac{z_3}{1+t^2} - \sin(r(t))$$

$$ z_4' = \frac{-z_1}{1+t^2} + \cos(r(t))$$

Comment: Woow, it was so easy... Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No, problem. If this answers your question, you can accept it to close. If you want a follow up practice problem, make this second order system autonomous.

Comment: I am going to accept this question, but  I have to wait 4 minutes hahahaha.

Comment: Okay, in that 4 minutes, accept the challenge and make this autonomous. :)